# Linux policy routing based on port number

Tags: routing, linux, pbr

How can I match the IP:Port pair in Linux to handle that packet via some particular table? Is that possible or traffic marking is the only way I can go?

Comment: You should probably ask this in on of the Linux forums.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any other way as marking the packets via iptables in the mangle chain and then use policy routing to base the routing on the mark.

So in my humble opinion "traffic marking" is the only way to go.

*Edit: A general explanation for policy-routing with iptables and ip can be found [here](http://www.taitclarridge.com/techlog/2009/10/iptables-route-traffic-from-specific-interface-to-a-specific-gateway.html) (this was the first explanation i found that takes into account that iptables and ip use different numeral systems (decimal / hexadecimal))*

Comment: Hi, could you please provide a link with explanation/examples for the average tech? That'll help all interested.

Comment: edited my answer